# Route Guard: How to make route guard true based on list sent by the server?

Tags: angular, typescript, post, angular-route-guards

I was trying to use route guard in my app that should let you go to a component only if the server sends you some parameters.

This is the list of the parameters that the server can send me (not all of them are sent each time)

```
  AGREEMENTS_VIEW 
  PROSPECTS_VIEW
  AGREEMENTS_INSERT_UPDATE
  PRODUCTS_INSERT_UPDATE
  PROSPECTS_INSERT_UPDATE
  DOCUMENTS_VIEW
  DOCUMENTS_INSERT_UPDATE
```

My route guard:

```
@Injectable()
export class UserRouteAccessService implements CanActivate {
    userActions=[];
    constructor(private router: Router, private securityService:CralSecurityService) {
     }
     securityActions(){debugger;
        this.securityService.securityActions().subscribe(
           (res: Array<actions>) => {
             this.userActions = res;
             console.log(res);

           });
       }


    canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): boolean {
        this.securityActions();

        if (this.userActions = actions ) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Now how can I tell in the if that its true when some of the paramenters are sent or not? is userActions=[] correct?  For example it should go to "true" when AGREEMENTS_VIEW 
  PROSPECTS_VIEW are sent.

Also, is this ok?

```
export class actions{
          AGREEMENTS_VIEW :string;
          PROSPECTS_VIEW :string;
          AGREEMENTS_INSERT_UPDATE :string;
          PRODUCTS_INSERT_UPDATE :string;
          PROSPECTS_INSERT_UPDATE :string;
          DOCUMENTS_VIEW :string;
          DOCUMENTS_INSERT_UPDATE :string;
}
```

> Http post:

```
securityActions(): <Array<any>> {
    return this.http.post<Array<any>>(
        `${this.ENDPOINT}/security-actions`,
        null,
    );
}
```

Comment: Keep in mind that `canActivate` can also return an Observable.

Answer (score 1):

The [signature of the interface](https://angular.io/api/router/CanActivate) is as follows :

```
interface CanActivate {
  canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean
}
```

This means you can return an HTTP call that returns a boolean.

So you can write this :

```
authorized = [
  'AGREEMENTS_VIEW',
  'PROSPECTS_VIEW',
  'AGREEMENTS_INSERT_UPDATE',
  'PRODUCTS_INSERT_UPDATE',
  'PROSPECTS_INSERT_UPDATE',
  'DOCUMENTS_VIEW',
  'DOCUMENTS_INSERT_UPDATE',
];

securityActions(): Observable<boolean> {
  return this.securityService.securityActions().pipe(
    map(response => this.authorized.includes(response))
  );
}


canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {
  return this.securityActions();
}
```

Comment: thank you for your help, "includes" says that the property doesnt exist in type 'string[]' and also in the canActivate method, return tell me that void is not assignable to type boolean :)

Comment: then use `.indexOf(response) !== -1`, and I edited my answer

Comment: still nothing "a function which declared type isnt "void" or "any" must return a value, this is on Observable<boolean>. Ive updated my post with the service where I have the HttpPost

Comment: My bad again, I was missing a `return` statement in securityActions !

Comment: thank you! last error, ( i hope :P ) on "response" in the securtyActions method  it tells me "the argument boolean is not assignable to parameter of  type "string". Ive tried also with ".indexOf(response) !== -1" but its the same thing ^^

Comment: If your service returns a boolean already, you can remove the `.pipe(
    map(response => this.authorized.includes(response))
  )` and just return `this.securityService.securityActions()`

Comment: my bad sorry i was just messing with my service, it actually returns an Array of strings